# Are shared addresses updated automatically when they change?

Tags: addresses

It would make sense that if Bob uses Sharon's address, when Sharon changes her address, Bob's address changes. However, in my experience that isn't the case or isn't the case all the time, unless you edit Bob's address.

What's supposed to happen? How and when is it supposed to happen?

Comment: What version are you on? Just tried on 5.56.2 and updated the contact the address belongs to and the contact that is sharing the address did update on hitting refresh.

Comment: 5.58.1. I would say it does work generally, but sometimes it doesn't. For instance, I can find contacts where the master address was updated via a profile on a contribution page and the other contacts address wasn't updated.

Comment: Expectation is anyone who 'shares' an address should show the updated address immediately after the 'owner' of the address makes a change (provided of course the Address that gets updated is the same Location Type etc etc as the one that is Shared, ie it is not creating a new address with a different (or worse duplicate) Location Type)

Comment: Turns out the problem is if the contact who is using the shared address updates it via profile, it looks like the address is still shared, but it actually isn't. Here's an issue to discuss how to fix this, as there are two options: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4479

Comment: I was wrong above, the contact with the master address updating their address works fine, it's when the contact who uses another contact's address updates their address that things break.